# Migrate Gitlab repo to TFS (Azure DevOps) include history and branches

Tags: git, tfs, gitlab

I've been searching the entire day and haven't found any answer yet.
I found how to migrate from TFS to Gitlab.
I wonder if there is any easy way to do the opposite - I mean to mirror or clone a gitlab repository to TFS with all of the branches (around 10 for each project) and history.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using GIT or TFVC as the version control system in Azure DevOps?

Comment: I am using GIT in Azure DevOps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose the following:

- Create an empty repository in Azure DevOps.
- Create a clone of that repo on your local drive.
- Add a repo from gitlab as a remote named `gitlab` to your local repo `git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/xxx/test.git`.
- Fetch all branches and tags from gitlab `git fetch --tags gitlab`.
- Push everything to Azure using `git push --all --tags origin`.

Now all branches and tags you have in gitlab should also be in Azure DevOps.

If you have multiple repos (it is not clear from your question) repeat the same process for every repo.

Answer (score -1):

If your TFS (Azure DevOps Server) can access the Gitlab repo, then you just need to import the Gitlab repository to Azure DevOps Server.

Get the repo URL, eg : `https://gitlab.com/xxx/test.git`, then enter the credential to import.

[image]

Otherwise, you can manually import a repo from Gitlab to TFS (Azure DevOps Server).

Please see [Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops) and [Move Git repositories to another project with full-fidelity history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/move-git-repos-between-team-projects?view=azure-devops) for details.

Comment: If I move it manually I need to move each repo and inside of each repo moving every branch manually.
I am looking to do so in a script or some other way.